# Creating a new meteor.js file and get error 100, MongoDB not able to write

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm playing with meteor.js and I get this error:

```
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.
Can't start mongod

MongoDB had an unspecified uncaught exception.
Check to make sure that MongoDB is able to write to its database directory.
```

I'm not sure how to remedy this, especially within the context of Meteor.js
I installed using curl on snow leopard mac os.

It was actually working for a while as I did a few exercises from a book I have, then it conked out with the error. Not sure what I did.

Comment: What OS is this? did you install meteor with sudo?

Comment: Oh sorry. Mac OS Snow lep. And I used curl

Comment: Could you check if theres a hidden `.meteor` folder in your app directory? also just see if `sudo meteor` works from your app directory?

Comment: Yes to both and I get the same error with sudo

Comment: ok if it did that with sudo, then try creating a new meteor app somewhere else and run it to see if that works? If that does, the app you made has its database/files changed around somehow

Comment: I created a whole new app on the desktop and a few other directories, same problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23279/discussion-between-akshat-and-taoist)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As with our discussion, you just need to free up some disk space, I wish meteor would give more descriptive errors.

If you free up some space it should sort itself out

Comment: This was happening a lot to me but freeing some space fixed the problem. (Weirdly some large db apps would work but smaller db apps wouldn't)

Answer (score 14):

I fixed this by going to `.meteor\local\db` and deleting `mongod.lock`

Comment: I encountered this issue after a sudden and unexpected shutdown. So, this makes sense.

Comment: +1 Exactly the solution I required. Frightened what would have happened if SO did not exist !

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, and it makes total sense in my situation (renamed the project dir while meteor was running).

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem when I updated from 0.7 to 0.8 in my local environment, I had nothing to loose in my local database, so I fixed by:

```
rm -rf .meteor/local/db
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you have an instance of `mongod` running already, do a

```
ps -el | grep mongo
```

and if it's running kill it and restart

Answer (score 0):

As @Akshat said:

If you even as root cannot run meteor, it's probably a full partion & you have to clean up or just move the folder to an other partition.

If you can run meteor as root, it's probably a rights issue solvable this way:
  In the meteor project folder: `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER .`
I recommend not to use a NTFS partition as setting the correct rights there is difficult.