# Running mongod in the background in Linux

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, vagrant

I would like to run mongodb on `vagrant`,I have used the following command:

```
 sudo mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --dbpath ./data
```

I have also tried modifying the above statement with all(cumulatively) and each of these options:

```
--logappend
--journal
--port 27017 and --port 27018
```

I get this error(with request to add journaling for durability and a notification that mongod will copy log to temporary file if journaling or logappend are disabled):

```
forked process: 5360
all output going to: /var/log/mongodb.log
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 100
```

I already have `mongodb` installed on my pc and it uses `27017` as the `port`,will this conflict with the error in running `mongod`

Comment: You're using Ubuntu, why not start it as a service? Set the required parameters in the config file instead of from the command line, then `sudo service mongd start`.

Comment: @SolarBear how would I do the config file?`sudo service mongod start` says unrecognized service

Comment: Did you install it from the Ubuntu package? What Ubuntu version are you using? On 12.04 the service was named `mongodb` IIRC ; the more recent version is named `mongod`.

Comment: If you are actually running MongoDB using vagrant you will not get a port clash. But I don't see any vagrant in the snippets you have posted. Have you tried looking at the logs in /var/log/mongodb.log?

Comment: Also, check for other questions related to the exit code 100, there are various possible causes (eg. disk is full : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25102414/unexpected-mongo-exit-code-100-restarting).

Comment: I can confirm that `mongodb` is running from `vagrant` when i use it with the service `mongodb` instead of `mongod`