# Getting 'unexpected mongo exit code 100' while running a meteor application

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am new to meteor .I started learning meteor language by referring a book 
'My First Meteor Application'...While i was running my application i am getting a 'unexpected mongo exit code 100' error.It is showing 'unexpected mongo exit code 100 restarting'.help me get over this error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meteor: unexpected mongo exit code 100](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610385/meteor-unexpected-mongo-exit-code-100)

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that either mongo process is still running in the background or it was killed improperly. You may use

```
try `ps -A | grep 'mongo'
```

to see what's going on. Either way, in your `.meteor/local/db` directory, there will be a non-empty `mongo.lock` file. If there's an active mongo process, kill it and the file should become empty. Otherwise remove the file manually. When you're done the error should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a common problem and there are multiple similar questions already out there with just as many suggested fixes. Problem is some of the proposed fixes either only work in certain cases or require using the `meteor reset` command which deletes the apps database(not ideal for everyone). I posted practically the same question a while back. I managed to solve it in my case and posted my answer to my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617615/meteor-unexpected-mongo-exit-code-100-restarting-cant-start-mongo-server/31643172#31643172). It seems to have fixed the issue for several people already without the need for `meteor reset` so it's worth a try if you haven't found a fix yet. Good luck!