# Can't run Rocket.Chat on Mac

Tags: macos, cordova, meteor, chat, rocket.chat

I'm trying to run the Rocket.Chat on my Mac & I'm getting this error. I've tried to fix it but I'm not having any luck with it.

Any idea on how I might be able to fix this?

I get the following error after I run the meteor command in Terminal:

```
    line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
    line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file

    .meteor/packages/meteor
    tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-           
    os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
    throw(ex);

    Error: Builder can not write without either data or a file path or 
    a symlink path: os/packages/rocketchat_livechat/public/head.html
    at Builder.write (/tools/isobuild/builder.js:225:13)
    at Builder.writeToGeneratedFilename    
    (/tools/isobuild/builder.js:353:10)
```

Comment: I had the same issue, but I'm not entirely sure how I fixed it. I was having an issue with some mongo DB locking, have you seen anything in the output about that?

I ended up following this to get it corrected: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31643172/2370599

Comment: Could also try running `meteor reset`? That will clear your database from what I understand, but I'm guessing you haven't gotten anything up and running yet.

Comment: Did you clone the repository from github? Have you tried with the latest version?