# Meteor: unexpected mongo exit code 100 when using ssh client on OS X

Tags: macos, mongodb, ssh, meteor

I've just installed Meteor 1.0 on my Ubuntu 12.04 VM in VirtualBox. After login via SSH from my OS X host and trying out the Meteor tutorial at https://www.meteor.com/try I get this exit code 100 from Mongo when I launch the example.

Here's the weird part, I only see this exit code 100 when I'm using OS X's terminal to SSH. If I try using putty on Windows or Chrome Secure Shell in my Chrome browser there is no problem. The Meteor app launches ok!

Is OS X's terminal/SSH implementation any different from putty or Chrome Secure Shell?

Comment: Might Duplicate of question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610385/meteor-unexpected-mongo-exit-code-100

Comment: it's different from that question. this is pertaining to the SSH client. not a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

OSX `ssh` is a version of OpenSSH, which is essentially the reference version of ssh. It's extremely unlikely that it's doing something unique or different than putty which prevents mongodb from working.

It *is* possible that you're using ssh differently than you're using putty, and that's preventing mongodb from working. You haven't given us any information about exactly how you're running ssh, or what putty options you're using. So there's no way for anyone to help you with that.

There are [numerous questions on this site about mongodb exit code 100](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmongodb%5D%20exit%20code%20100). Common causes seem to be lack of disk space and inability to delete a lock file. If you were using a different ubuntu account when you connect from OSX vs putty, that could certainly cause trouble deleting a lock file, for example.

Comment: for putty i'm using all the default settings, just entering the IP address of the VM and entering the username and password. for OSX SSH i'm using the command ssh user1@ip from terminal. in both cases i'm using the same user account user1. the fact that i can run the meteor app from 2 different ssh clients prove that it's not a permissions or diskspace issue. it's really weird and i hope someone here can shed some light.

Comment: My next step would be to run the command that is failing under [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) and see exactly what system call is failing to make mongo exit.