# Javascript callback returns "undefined" using neo4j and meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, callback, neo4j

for my Bachelor thesis I am required to build a Web frontend/ visualisation for a business process, using javascript. This process is stored inside a neo4j database (version 2.1.7) and I am using meteor together with the driver, which is recommended on neo4j's website (version 2.10).

Since I am fairly new to Web development in general and especialy to javascript, I am not sure if my problem is of a technical or knowledge (aka me being a beginner) nature.

At the moment I am working on a function, which should give me back a node from the database (currently "a node" equals a node's id, since the final representation of a node on the webpage is not yet decided).

```
getNodeById = function getNodeById(id){
    console.log("The given id is " + id);  
    var result = undefined;

    N4JDB.getNodeById(id, function getNode(node) {

      console.log ("The node's id is " + node.id);
      console.log("Result before " + result );
      result = node.id;
      console.log("Result after " +result);

    });
return result;

}
```

Calling getNodeById(4) gives me the following output on meteor's console:

I20150309-16:03:32.200(1)? The given id is 4 
I20150309-16:03:32.272(1)? The node's id is undefined
I20150309-16:03:32.272(1)? Result before undefined
I20150309-16:03:32.272(1)? Result after undefined

The problem right now is, that I am not sure how to write a callback function, which fits for the drivers getNodeById function.

Link to the driver's documentation: https://atmospherejs.com/ostrio/neo4jdriver

Edit:Further debugging has lead me to believe, that I make a mistake somewhere/how when invoking N4JDB.getNodeById since it always returns null

New function (require statement on top of the file, since there will be many functions similar to this one)looks like this

```
getNodeById = function getNodeById(id){
  var myFuture = new Future ();
  var result = undefined;
  N4JDB.getNodeById(id, function getNode(node){
      console.log(node);
      result = node.id;
      myFuture.return(result);
    });
  return myFuture.wait();
}
```

Final edit: It worked with

```
   getNodeById = function getNodeById(id){
      var myFuture = new Future ();
      var result = undefined;
      N4JDB.getNodeById(id, function getNode(err,node){
          //console.log(node);
          result = node.id;
          myFuture.return(result);
        });
      return myFuture.wait();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor is based to node.js, so it works asynchronously.
Your code starts to execute the function, but not waits for the result.

A good solution can be use the fibers/future npm package, as is explained at this link.
https://www.discovermeteor.com/patterns/5828399

So:

```
getNodeById = function getNodeById(id){
    Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
    var myFuture = new Future();
    var result = undefined;

    N4JDB.getNodeById(id, function getNode(node) {
        result = node.id;
        myFuture.return(result);
    });

    return myFuture.wait();

}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried this, but it seems incompatible with something in my meteor/mongodb files, since it caused the error described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610385/meteor-unexpected-mongo-exit-code-100

Comment: Did you install meteorhacks:npm and configured the packges.json?

Comment: I have meteor and npm set up (to get the neo4j driver), but I did not do any further configuration.

Comment: So you have the packages.json configured in this way?

{
    "future": "2.3.1",
    "neo4j": "2.0.0-alpha5"
}

And you are using neo4j in this way?

var neo4j = Meteor.npmRequire('neo4j');

Comment: I am using a different driver (https://atmospherejs.com/ostrio/neo4jdriver), using neo4j like this: this.N4JDB = new Meteor.Neo4j;

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using Meteor's Neo4jDriver, you can simply run and execute Cypher query.

```
var foundByID = new ReactiveVar(null);
N4JDB.query('MATCH (s) WHERE id(s) = {myNodeID} RETURN s;', {myNodeID: 123}, function(error, result){
   if(error){
       //Throw error here
       throw new Meteor.Error(500, error);
   }
   foundByID.set(result);
});
```

Or use [Neo4jReactivity](https://atmospherejs.com/ostrio/neo4jreactivity) package